# Legend for combined graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, legend-properties

I am trying to reproduce this figure (without the Portugal highlight):
[image]

The data (and figure) can be found in this link: https://stat.link/uz49al.

I imported and reshaped the data into a long format, but then I got stuck on how it would be possible to rearrange the legend entries in the same order as in the original.

I would very much appreciate your help!

Thanks!

Here is where I got:

```
# load data
f5_5_data_before <-
  read_excel("uz49al.xlsx", sheet = "Figure1.20", range = "A32:E68")
names(f5_5_data_before)[1] <- "Country"
names(f5_5_data_before)[2] <- "Odds_ratio"
names(f5_5_data_before)[3] <- "SE"
names(f5_5_data_before)[4] <- "sig"
names(f5_5_data_before)[5] <- "non_sig"
f5_5_data_before$Country <- as.factor(f5_5_data_before$Country)

f5_5_data_before <- f5_5_data_before %>%
  mutate(
    category = case_when(
      is.na(sig) ~ "Non-significant",
      !is.na(sig) ~ "Significant"
    ),
    value = case_when(
      category == "Non-significant" ~ non_sig,
      category == "Significant" ~ sig
    )
  )
f5_5_data_before$group2 <- "Before accounting for reading performance"

f5_5_data_after <-
  read_excel("uz49al.xlsx", sheet = "Figure1.20", range = "A32:I68")
f5_5_data_after <- f5_5_data_after[, c(1, 6:9)]
names(f5_5_data_after)[1] <- "Country"
names(f5_5_data_after)[2] <- "Odds_ratio"
names(f5_5_data_after)[3] <- "SE"
names(f5_5_data_after)[4] <- "sig"
names(f5_5_data_after)[5] <- "non_sig"
f5_5_data_after$Country <- as.factor(f5_5_data_after$Country)

f5_5_data_after <- f5_5_data_after %>%
  mutate(
    category = case_when(
      is.na(sig) ~ "Non-significant",
      !is.na(sig) ~ "Significant"
    ),
    value = case_when(
      category == "Non-significant" ~ non_sig,
      category == "Significant" ~ sig
    )
  )
f5_5_data_after$group2 <- "After accounting for reading performance"

# appending in long format
f5_5_data <- rbind(f5_5_data_after, f5_5_data_before)

# shaded rectangle
rect1 <- data.frame(
  xmin = 14.5,
  xmax = 15.5,
  ymin = -Inf,
  ymax = Inf
)

# figure
f5_5 <- ggplot() +
  geom_col(data = f5_5_data %>% filter(group2 == "After accounting for reading performance"),
           aes(x = reorder(Country,-Odds_ratio),
               y = value,
               fill = category,
               colour = group2),
           width=0.5,
  ) +
  geom_point(
    data = f5_5_data %>% filter(group2 == "Before accounting for reading performance"),
    aes(x = Country,
        y = value,
        fill = category,
        colour = group2),
    shape = 23,
    size = 3,
  ) +
  geom_rect(
    data = rect1,
    aes(
      xmin = xmin,
      xmax = xmax,
      ymin = ymin,
      ymax = ymax
    ),
    alpha = 0.5,
    inherit.aes = FALSE
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = pretty_breaks(),
                     limits = c(0, 25),
                     expand = c(0, 0)) +
  labs(x = NULL,
       y = "Odds ratio") +
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))
print(f5_5)
```

This yields the following output:
[image]

As you can see, the legend looks substantially different and essentially I got stuck.

Comment: Could you please provide some data -> `dput()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option to achieve your desired result would be via the `ggnewscale` package which allows for multiple scales for the same aesthetic. Doing so we could map `category` on the `fill` aes in both the `geom_col` and the `geom_point` but have two different legends:

Note: I simplified your data wrangling code a bit.

```
library(readxl)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggnewscale)

url <- "https://stat.link/uz49al"
download.file(url, destfile = "uz49al.xlsx")

dat <- read_excel("uz49al.xlsx", sheet = "Figure1.20", range = "A32:I68")
dat <- list(
  before = setNames(dat[, 1:5], c("Country", "Odds_ratio", "SE", "sig", "non_sig")),
  after = setNames(dat[, c(1, 6:9)], c("Country", "Odds_ratio", "SE", "sig", "non_sig"))
) %>%
  bind_rows(.id = "group2") 

dat <- dat %>%
  mutate(
    category = if_else(is.na(sig), "nonsig", "sig"),
    value = if_else(is.na(sig), non_sig, sig)
  ) %>%
  select(-sig, -non_sig)

group2_labels <- c(after = "After accounting for reading performance", before = "Before accounting for reading performance")

rect1 <- data.frame(xmin = 14.5, xmax = 15.5,  ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf)

ggplot(dat, aes(x = reorder(Country,-Odds_ratio), y = value)) +
  geom_col(data = ~filter(.x, group2 == "after"), aes(fill = category), width = 0.5) +
  scale_fill_manual(labels = NULL, values = c(sig = "darkblue", nonsig = "steelblue"), 
                    name = group2_labels[["after"]], guide = guide_legend(title.position = "right")) +
  new_scale_fill() +
  geom_point(data = ~filter(.x, group2 == "before"), aes(fill = category), size = 3, shape = 23, color = "lightblue") +
  geom_rect(data = rect1, aes(xmin = xmin, xmax = xmax, ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax),
            alpha = 0.5, inherit.aes = FALSE) +
  scale_fill_manual(labels = NULL, values = c(nonsig = "white", sig = "lightblue"), breaks = c("sig", "nonsig"),
                    name = group2_labels[["before"]], guide = guide_legend(title.position = "right")) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = scales::pretty_breaks(), limits = c(0, 25), expand = c(0, 0)) +
  labs(x = NULL, y = "Odds ratio") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1),
        legend.position = "top")
```

[image]